# Foreverjs can't start server

Tags: daemon, forever

Trying to run `forever start server.js`. It prints like `info:    Forever processing file: server.js` and really script isn't executed. With no errors.

If i run like `sudo forever start server.js` than it starts normally.
And `forever server.js` runs good as well, but it's not like daemon.

How can i run script as daemon w/o sudo?

Comment: It's standard behavior that non-privileged users are not allowed to bind to privileged ports (port numbers below 1024). If you run your server in a port >1024, you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: i use >1024 ports, otherwise i'd get `Error: listen EACCES` when run w/o `forever server.js`

Comment: Do you have the same error when you run `node server.js`?

Comment: no i don't. Generally i was meaning, that port in not the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forever has log file `~/.forever/forever.log` and there was info, that "forever" can't start server if `~/.forever` don't have write permission, so `chmod +w -R ~/.forever` was the solution